# Send message using excel to whatsapp web reloading

Tags: excel, vba, whatsapp, sendkeys

Hi I have the code to send messages from excel to Whatsapp, but every time the code opens a new tab of Whatsapp web instead of using the already opened WhatsApp web tab. (Using Google Chrome)

Here is the code

```
Sub Test()

    Dim text As String
    Dim contact As String
    text = Range("C2").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=" https://web.whatsapp.com/"
    If MsgBox("Is WhatsApp Loaded?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Press No To Cancel", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbSystemModal, "WhatsApp") = vbYes Then
        Fazer (100)
        startrow = 2
        startcol = 2
        Do Until Sheets(1).Cells(startrow, 1) = ""
            contact = Cells(startrow, 1)
            text1 = Sheets(1).Cells(startrow, startcol).Value
            Fazer (3000)
                Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys(contact, True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys("~", True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys(text1, True)
            Fazer (1000)
                Call SendKeys("~", True)
            Fazer (1000)
            startrow = startrow + 1
        Loop
    Else
    End If
End Sub

Function Fazer(ByVal Acao As Double)
    Application.Wait (Now() + Acao / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Send_MultiWAMsg()
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("W_C").Cells
    If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        Range("W_N").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Range("W_L").Value
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
        ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "(~)"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "^{F4}", True
    End If
    Next
    Set cell = Nothing
    Call SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}", True)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

***Inputs***

1. Range("W_C") = A list of Contacts' telephone numbers
2. Range("W_N") = Selected Contact Number
3. Range("W_M") = WhatsApp Message (text)
4. Range("W_L") = Complete WhatsApp Hyperlink (formula ...
   =HYPERLINK("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="&TRIM(W_N)&"&text="&W_M)

Comment: please do not add explanations in different answer, instead edit the answer with code and append this part there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ExcelToWhatsApp_TextT_Msg()

'*********************************

Dim whatsapp_number As String

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value <> "Yes" Then   '' Check Skip

        whatsapp_number = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value
    
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%2B" & whatsapp_number & "&text=" & _
        Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value & "&app_absent=1&send=1"
    
      
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:08"))

            VBA.SendKeys "~", True
            
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            
             
    End If

Next i

MsgBox "All WhatsApp Messages SuccessFully Sended", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.